# Closure Property of Subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$ and $H \leq N_{G}(K) $, then $HK$ is subgroup of G.

I already know that I can prove it by $HK=KH$.

But why can't I just prove it  by $H \leq G$ and $K \leq G$, then $HK \leq G$?

I have the quetion, because when $A$ and $B$ are subegroup of $G$, $A \leq N_{G}(B)$ and $B \leq N_{G}(B)$ can imply  $AB \leq N_{G}(B) $ .

What's the main difference of the above statement?

Comment: For the first question: Try some examples to see that the product need not be a subgroup.

Comment: There are lots of examples where $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$, but $HK$ is not a subgroup.  Hint: make sure that neither $H$ nor $K$ is normal in $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G=S_3$, $H=\langle(12)\rangle$ and $K=\langle (13)\rangle$.  Then,
$$
HK=\{(),(12),(13),(12)(13)\}.
$$
$HK$, however, cannot be a subgroup because $|HK|=4$ while $|S_3|=6$ and $4\nmid 6$.  The smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $HK$ is $G$ itself.

The problem is that $h_1k_1h_2$ can't be written in the form $hk$ for some $h\in H$ and $k\in K$.  The problem is the closure property.  The extra conditions that you mention are used to reduce any element of the form $h_1k_1h_2$ into something of the form $hk$.

Certainly, for your problem, since $H\leq N_G(K)$ and we always have $K\leq N_G(K)$, $HK\leq N_G(K)$, so $HK$ must be a group and since it is a subset of $G$ it must be a subgroup of $G$.